# Playwright finds too much elements by text

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

I tried to find all the elements that has the text "Operation" inside them. I only see one such element visible, but Playwright is giving me 19:

```
 self.page.locator('*', has_text='Operation').click()
```

When I run this selector in the developer tools:

```
$x('//*[contains( text(),"Operation" )]')
```

I see only a single element.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe looking inside a specific div or container will be more robust. looking inside the whole page can show such inconsistencies imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the text locator and also add more Texts along with `Operation` to pinpoint your element more accurately.

```py
page.locator("text=Operation").click()
page.locator("text=Some more words Operation").click()
```

Or, you can also use the Nth element selector if you know the position of the text occurrence. Starts from `0`

```py
page.locator("text=Operation >> nth=0").click()
```